# How to make the memory address of two variables equal in Python?

Tags: python, pointers, variables

I need to equal the memory address of two variables...
I mean If the value of the first variable changes, the second variable will also take the same value.
For example :

```
    a = 10

    b = 10

    # now addresses are same

    a = 5
    print(b)  # must print 5
```

I want to do something like this:
id(a) = id(b)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You cannot.

Comment: The Python data model doesn't have any notion of memory addresses. Variables in Python simply do not work they way you are expecting. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: The fact that `a` and `b` refer to the same `int` object is an implementation-specific optimization of CPython, not something guaranteed by the Python language itself.

Comment: I don't believe you can automatically bind two variables together this way.  Also only ***small*** integers will be actually share the same memory.

Comment: You could get *close* to this, in very specific use cases, for an instance attribute paired with a `property` that accesses it. But it'll never work for top-level names like this. The fact that you want to do it at all likely indicates [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).